# Rpi 4 with Ubuntu Server tether network with usb-c

Tags: networking, usb, 19.10, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB were I have installed Ubuntu Server 19.10, I'm trying to get network and power over a USB-C cable to an Ipad Pro. I follwed this [tutorial](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2019/11/02/pi4-usb-c-gadget/) to get it working with Raspian Buster and it worked. But I want to utilize the 64-bit support from Ubuntu.

I need help to figure out how to setup the network from the USB-C cable.

Any ideas are welcome :)

- I have check/update the bootloader
- I have added total_mem=3072 to /usercfg.txt so USB is working

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1007-raspi2 #8-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 12:42:47 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to get help, which is probably why you are being downvoted.  I suggest: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you got it to work? I'm trying to achieve the same, but I'm not familiar with Linux and the folders and files are not present in the same location as the tutorial. RPI4 and Ubuntu 64bit 19.10.

Comment: @jonas no unfortunately not. Let me know if you find a solution elsewhere!

Comment: Still no solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Tbe version of Ubuntu you used likely doesn't support USB properly.

Canonical have just released a new Ubuntu 19.10.1 server image for Rasberry pi which supports USB and sees 4Gb on pi 4 out of the box.

[Here it is](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

Comment: Did not help me unfortunately, since I need to translate the commands from Raspbian to Ubuntu, files and folders are not in the same places.